# PHP with HTML output as Object

Tags: php, html

Is there a way to use html in php like in javascript, where I can do `Element.append()` or so. Like `$html->body->header->append($menu)`? Some class or something?

Comment: Take a look at [DOM](http://php.net/DOM), it's basically the same API that you know from JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [DOM in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php). Basically, [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) provides functions similar to the Javascript DOM ones, although the DOM is a bit more difficult/complex to use in PHP.